# how to get list items fields using CSOM

Tags: client-object-model, csom

I have to get other column value of list item whose "Title" matches with entered string in text box from the page. I am using CAML query to match "Title". But in Success function, how to get that item's other field like ...Title, Department etc.. Below if my tried code.

Code in CEWP:

```
<input name="pop" id="pop" type="text"/> <input name="b1" id="b1" onclick="getTheList()" type="button" value="Submit"/><script>

function getTheList() {
alert('inside getTheList fucntion');

 var test=$("#pop").val();
 alert(test); 
 clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var web = clientContext.get_web();
 var myList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('URL_List');
 var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
 query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title"/><Value Type="Text">+ test + </Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');      
 this.ListItem = myList.getItems(query); 
 clientContext.load(ListItem,'title'); 
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.mySuccessFunction), Function.createDelegate(this, this.myFailFunction));
return false;
}

function mySuccessFunction(sender, args) 
{    
alert('Success');
var title = this.ListItem.get_item("Title"); 
alert(title);
//how to get title and other field if an Item here...??
  }
function myFailFunction(sender, args) 
{ 
alert('inside fail');
 alert("GetListItemById Failed. \n" + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace()); 
 }</script>
```

Comment: its giving me Title undefined..!

Comment: clientContext.load(ListItem,'Title'); instead of title. Missing uppercase?

Comment: nope...Does not work..:(

Comment: Replace 'CSOM' to 'JSOM' in title please.

Answer (score 1):

As part of `context.load` you need to request for details which you need

Something like

```
clientContext.load(ListItem,'Include(Title,Department)';
```

Fix following error in your code

```
 query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title"/><Value Type="Text">+ test + </Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
```

to

```
 query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title"/><Value Type="Text">'+ test + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
```

**Update (Below code is working for me**

```
<input name="pop" id="pop" type="text"/> <input name="b1" id="b1" onclick="getTheList()" type="button" value="Submit"/><script>

<script>
    var ListItem;
    function getTheList() {
        alert('inside getTheList fucntion');
        var test=$("#pop").val();
        alert(test); 
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        var myList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('URL_List');
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title"/><Value Type="Text">' + test + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');      
        ListItem = myList.getItems(query); 
        clientContext.load(ListItem,'Include(Title)'); 
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.mySuccessFunction), Function.createDelegate(this, this.myFailFunction));
        return false;
    }

    function mySuccessFunction(sender, args) 
    {    
        var listItemEnumerator = ListItem.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext())        {
        var item = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var title = item.get_item('Title');
 }      }
    function myFailFunction(sender, args) 
    { 
        alert('inside fail');
        alert(args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace()); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks Amal but it didnt work!

Comment: @RajeevK your CAML query is wrong. Try my updated answer

Comment: no..its not working..

Comment: thanks for your help Amal..! I appreciate :) but i really wonder why its not working at my place..! really strange.! frustrating.!

Comment: Use the code I posted above. And modify mySuccessFunction to loop through the result as Nadeem suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`clientContext.load(ListItem,'title');`  should be `clientContext.load(ListItem,'Include(Title)');`. In order to show other fields just add them in  `Include` section separated by commas. For example `'Include(Title, Id)'`. Make sure to use internal names of the fields.

**Update**

You need to loop through the list items in `success` handler that you get using the query, something like this:

```
var listItemEnumerator = this.ListItem.getEnumerator();
 while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
     var item = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
     var title = item.get_item('Title');
     }
```

Comment: I tried this..but it did not work for me..! Is there any other mistake in code..?!

Comment: all the way it gives me title undefined.! what I am trying is..I have one text box from where I am entering some string..and comparing that with Title of items through caml query.

Comment: i tried this also..didnt help.! Damn..! can figure out whts the problem in code..!

Comment: finally I succeeded with REST and Sp services. Thanks for your help. really appreciate ..:)